# can a binary search tree has two branches only?

Tags: tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

According to [GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search-tree-data-structure/), a binary tree is a BST when:

> The left subtree of a node contains only nodes with keys lesser than the node’s key.
> The right subtree of a node contains only nodes with keys greater than the node’s key.
> The left and right subtree each must also be a binary search tree.

I wonder if a tree like following can still be considered as BST?

```
     3
   2   4
 1       5
0
```

Comment: Technically yes, but the structure of this example removes its efficiency advantage and makes it like an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word - yes. There is no requirement that the tree be "full" (i.e., every node should have exactly two children.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it fulfills the requirements, so it is a binary search tree. Even this degenerate case is still a binary search tree:

```
        4
       /
      3
     /
    2
   /
  1
```

For reasons of efficiency, binary search trees that can be updated (with insertion or deletion), are usually rebalanced, so to minimise their height. Different techniques exist to balance binary search trees. See [self balancing binary search tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree).